# Do I need to send release to my instance variable in the dealloc method? (iOS)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

In my class dealloc method I have

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    [searchField release]; 
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Where searchField is defined in the class variables.

```
@interface SearchCell : UITableViewCell
{
    UISearchBar *searchField;
    id delegate;
}
```

The class is used with the following way:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        SearchCell *mycell = [[SearchCell alloc] init];
        [cell setDelegate:self];
        return [mycell autorelease];
    }
```

searchField is created here:

```
- (id) init
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    [self create];

    return self;
}

- (void) create
{
    searchField = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    searchField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;    
    [self addSubview:searchField];
}
```

Do I need to use [searchField release]; in my dealloc? The application crashes with message: "**[UISearchBar respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance **".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be aware of object ownership rules. In manual retain & release environment (as opposed to ARC) the rules for Objective-C objects can be remembered with the acronym **NARC**.

If you have a reference to an object that you created fresh using **new** or **alloc**, or any object that you called **retain** on, or any object you created by calling **copy** or **mutableCopy** on another, or any object created by any methods that start with any of these names (e.g. `newInstance`), then
**you own that object** and before you are deallocated you **must** release it.

But, if you didn't do any of those things, then you **do not own that object**, and **must not** release it. [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)

In your case - you don't show the code where you set the value `searchField`, but from the crash I'd imagine you never take ownership of the object. Show the code where you assign to `searchField` and we'll all know for sure.
**EDIT**: You do take ownership by creating it with `alloc`. You need to keep the `release` there in `dealloc`. Is it being released from somewhere else? Or is the cell itself possibly getting overreleased?

Comment: [UISearchBar respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Answer (score 1):

No, don't release it there. Since you return it with "autorelease", the next run through your event loop will automatically decrease the retain count.

When you finally hit your "dealloc" method, the retain count is already 0 and your app will raise an exception.

Comment: what happens if an object use it without autorelease?

Comment: Then, of course, the receiver of the object (the function/object which is using the return value of your code) is responsible to release it after use.

I misread your code a bit: You're releasing `searchField`, but you are not showing how you create it.